# OpenCL static C++ documentation

Tags: c#, c++, opencl, gpgpu

I have been experimenting with OpenCL for quite a few days now, I'm using AMD's SDK and I'm now able to run a simple kernel in parallel and passing input/output to/from it.
I have to say though that I'm very disappointed by the lack of proper documentation for it, CUDA seems much more mature than OpenCL, but I cannot use CUDA because I don't have nVidia and because I want portable code.

I have read that AMD's OpenCL SDK now supports "static C++" extension which allows you to have  some C++ features for writing the kernels, like inheritance and passing classes instances from the host to the device. However I cannot find ANY documentation for that or any examples.

### To be short, my question is:

Where can I find documentation about using OpenCL's static C++ extension?
An extra question would be, where can I find PROPER documentation for the C++ wrapper (1.2 and **not 1.1**)

a super extra (:P) question would be, is there any complete/mature C# wrappers for OpenCL 1.2?? so far I found OpenCL.NET which is working fine, but again it doesn't have documentation so I have to look at the OpenCL C Reference and try to find the equivalent in C#

Thanks for reading this, I understand it's kind of ambiguous, all I want is an easy to use OpenCL SDK with proper documentation (Except C of course, I hate using plain C).

Comment: I had the same issue a couple months ago. I even posted on the OpenCL forum to get some help - zero answers. Nil. There is only one sample in the AMD SDK using classes and it's not even interesting. Here is the static C++ [extension document](http://tinyurl.com/c2mojfv), for what it's worth (you've probably already seen it).

Comment: yup, I have already seen that document, it gives one small example, they can't even write the whole code, they just write a snippet and "...". Very disappointing.

Comment: I don't think there is a C++ wrapper for OpenCL 1.2. The `cl.hpp` header file available on the [Khronos website](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/) has not been updated to 1.2. There is a chapter on how to use the OpenCL 1.1 C++ bindings in the [OpenCL programming guide](http://www.amazon.com/OpenCL-Programming-Guide-Aaftab-Munshi/dp/0321749642).

Comment: Another OpenCL C# wrapper is "Cloo" (http://sourceforge.net/projects/cloo/) but its maturity and support for OpenCL 1.2 might be equivalent to OpenCL.Net.

Comment: yea I know about Cloo, but I discarded it after I found out that it doesn't support 1.2 which has been released a while back, so it seems outdated. However, after reading about what's new in 1.2 it seems like nothing relevant to me anyway, and Cloo has good documentation and starting examples, so I think I will just use it for now.

Comment: The `cl.hpp` support OpenCL 1.2:
`/*! \file
 *
 *   \brief C++ bindings for OpenCL 1.0 (rev 48), OpenCL 1.1 (rev 33) and 
 *       OpenCL 1.2 (rev 15)    
 *   \author Benedict R. Gaster, Laurent Morichetti and Lee Howes
 *   
 *   Additions and fixes from:
 *       Brian Cole, March 3rd 2010 and April 2012 
 *       Lee Howes, October 2011, March 2012
 *       Matt Gruenke, April 2012.
 *   
 *   \version 1.2.1
 *   \date September 2012
 *
 *   Optional extension support
 *
 *         cl
 *         cl_ext_device_fission
 *    #define USE_CL_DEVICE_FISSION
 */`

Comment: @Alex it seems like you are correct it does say so in the file itself, even though the website says "This header works for all versions of OpenCL, but has not yet been updated with new OpenCL 1.2 entry points."
Anyway, I figured out that 1.2 doesn't have features that I need, my main question really was about finding proper documentation for OpenCL especially the "static c++" extension which allows you to have classes in your kernel code among other features that should make your life easier. Thanks for this note though

Comment: Both AMD's and NVidia's OpenCL implementations are broken and can't be used for production code. I have had endless issues with kernels working perfect on one platform/device and not working on another. And this is for very simple things like FFTs. Anyone who thinks otherwise, I say this: try your opencl code on AMD/GPU, AMD/CPU, NVidia/GPU, and Intel/CPU opencl and let me know if it works across all of them. I'd bet it doesn't. AMD's forum is a bug reporting tool. All you will be doing is reporting OpenCL implementation bugs.